# Upload a file on Button click in asp

Tags: javascript, file-upload, windows-ce

I am working on classic ASP with WinCE OS. I want to upload a file from WinCE and Save in the local machine. Please share the necessary JScript function for file upload which i can put it in a include file. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for reminding Derek, i have accepted the answer. Now please help me with Uploading the file.

Comment: I upvoted the question so more people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use any JavaScript library.. like jQuery..

Here are the file upload examples..

http://pixelcone.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-script/

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Cheers :)

Comment: I cant use JQuery plugins as it is from WinCE OS and classic ASP. Please suggest the alternative way.

Comment: you need pure javascript solutions ?

Comment: This is old approach.. but see if it can work http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

I have no information about asp classic but I have used Asp.net and you can use asp to receive file in order to upload file from wince use can develop app using c# here is an example.

Its client WinCE Application Code Function Upload(string Path, String FileName) takes File Path and File Name as Input and Post it to web page

```
#region Upload
public bool Upload(string FilePath, string FileName)
{
string Url = "HTTP://test.mtsonweb.com/fileupload.ashx"; //  Change it to your page name
string BytesConfirmedReceived = "";
int BytesSent = 0;
bool Ret = false;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
try
{

if (File.Exists(FilePath +"\\"+ FileName) == false) { return true; }

//FileInfo oInfo = new FileInfo(FilePath + "\\" + FileName);
//BytesSent = Convert.ToInt32(oInfo.Length.ToString());

Url += "?myfile=" + FileName.Trim();

FileStream fr = new FileStream(FilePath + "\\" + FileName, FileMode.Open);

BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fr);
byte[] FileContents = r.ReadBytes((int)fr.Length);
BytesSent = FileContents.Length;

r.Close();
fr.Close();

WebRequest oRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url);

oRequest.Method = "POST";

oRequest.Timeout = 15000;

oRequest.ContentLength = FileContents.Length;

Stream oStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream();

BinaryWriter oWriter = new BinaryWriter(oStream);

oWriter.Write(FileContents);

oWriter.Close();

oStream.Close();

WebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();
BytesConfirmedReceived = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream(),
Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();

oResponse.Close();

if (BytesSent.ToString() == BytesConfirmedReceived.Trim())
{
Ret = true;
}

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
return Ret;

}
#endregion
```

Now of you page you can handle file uploaded using script whatever you want, I have used asp.net with c# as back-end and below is the source of page:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileUpload" %>
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;

public class FileUpload : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext oContext)
{

int BytesSent = 0;
//string LocalPath = @"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\";

string MyFile = "";


try
{

MyFile = oContext.Request["myfile"].ToString().Trim();
MyFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Demo/Files/" +

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

BytesSent = oContext.Request.TotalBytes;

Class1 obj = Class1.GetInstance();

obj.FileName = MyFile;
obj.FileLength = BytesSent;

byte[] InComingBinaryArray =
oContext.Request.BinaryRead(oContext.Request.TotalBytes);
obj.Data = InComingBinaryArray;

if (File.Exists(MyFile) == true)
{
File.Delete(MyFile);
}

FileStream fs = new FileStream(MyFile, FileMode.CreateNew);
BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);
w.Write(InComingBinaryArray);
w.Close();
fs.Close();

FileInfo oInfo = new FileInfo(MyFile);
long a = (long)BytesSent;

oContext.Response.Write(oInfo.Length.ToString());

}
catch (Exception err) { oContext.Response.Write(err.Message); }

}

public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

}
```